# import in react give this error ';' expected.ts(1005)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

As you can see from the photo we have this error
I delete latest version of the typescript globally but I see this issue

Comment: remove the 'quotes' from 'Login'

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
import Login from './Login';
```

instead of

```
import 'Login' from './Login';
```

> The way you are importing is correct, just remove '' from 'Login' because you're making it string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple response: you have a space between import path and semicolon